# Registering non-isotropic CT scans with different field of view

Tags: python, image-processing, medical, image-registration, simpleitk

I am very new to medical image registration.

I am trying to register two CT volumes, the first is axial with size of (384,384,31) and spacing of (0.57,0.57,4.8) and the second is a sagittal scan with size of (384,384,15) and spacing (0.67,0.67,2.2) in order to use the area of overlap between them to create super-resolution and obtain an isotropic scan.

So the problem is that the volumes have a different orientation as well as the different field of view. I.e. the axial slices in the sagittal scan contain only a small segment of what is present in the axial scan, In other words, I need to crop the axial slices in the axial scan to match the FOV of the sagittal slice and so on to create masks for the simpleitk rigid registration algorithm.

I also think that I need the masks for resampling both volumes at some point.

My question is, How can I create the mask and can I use any of the metadata available in the nifti file to do that? I have the direction, origin and index point matrix.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I'll start with some comments:

1. In the SimpleITK world, both of your images are volumes, there is no fundamental difference (axial vs. sagittal). The volumes simply have different spacing which is implicitly taken into account by the registration framework.
2. I am not sure what you mean when you refer to a sagittal CT scan. CTs are reconstructed/computed into axial slices (x,y with smaller spacing than along the z axis which is the scan direction along the head-foot direction). This appears to be consistent with the parameters of your two volumes, so not sure why you refer to one as axial and the other sagittal.

To address your registration question:

I would use a mask on the fixed image to indicate the expected region of overlap (e.g. bottom 1/2 of the image) so you don't need to crop anything. You then need to set an initial transformation so that this region overlaps lets say with the top 1/2 of the second image. The combination of mask and initialization will have the registration algorithm sample points in the relevant region and map
them to the moving image.

Finally, as you are new to medical image registration you may benefit from going over our [Jupyter notebooks](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/SimpleITK-Notebooks) specifically notebook 65 uses masks, although I expect other registration notebooks may help you too.